# user_passes_test and Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have specific subjects related with specific users in my application. How to limit their access to just their subjects?

I have idea to use like

```
usersub = get_object_or_404(UserSubject, user=request.user, subject=subject)
```

If there is no relation, it will throw 404 error. But is there any other way to complete it with user_passes_test decorator?

Comment: Yes, but you would have to write your own decorator to do that. I don't think user_passes_test can accept view's parameters. But from your example, this decorator will get pretty limited usage, so why write decorator for something that can be done with just get_object_or_404 ?

Comment: so it is good? What about SQL queries... One page makes a lot of queries (35 of them in 20-25ms). Is it good?

Comment: get_object_or_404 does pretty much the same thing as regular objects.get query wrapped in try/except. So its not slower than doing all that yourself. But if your page makes alot of queries (like 35), then THAT could be an issue.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can use [`exists`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.exists)

```
if UserSubject.objects.filter(user=request.user, subject=subject).exists():
    # what you want to do
else:
    # do something else
```

or just [`filter`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.filter)

```
usersub = UserSubject.objects.filter(user=request.user, subject=subject)
if usersub:
    # do something
else:
    # do something else
```

Those will make your check but will not raise an Exception or return a `Http404`.

Update: You must write your own decorator, since `user_passes_test`  can nor handle your situation. Here is an example decorator:

```
from django.http import HttpResponseForbidden

def subject_test(f, subject):
    def test_user_for_subject(request, subject, *args, **kwargs):
        if not UserSubject.objects.filter(user=request.user, subject=subject).exists():
            retun HttpResponseForbidden('Access denied!')
        else:
            return f(request, *args, **kwargs)
    return test_user_for_subject
```

An in your views :

```
@subject_test('your subject here')
def your_view_is_in_here(request):
    ...
```

But the hard part is, you must pass all your filter arguments unless they are reachable from `request`

Comment: hmmm... I need to throw 404 or something like forbidden access. This is too much lines for one check and it do same thing as get_object_or_404 does... I am asking just about performance